# how to create scroll view with images in Horizontal through programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiscrollview

Hi I am new to iOS how to create scroll view with images programmatically

like this I have tried, I am getting scroll view with images in horizontal but the images are placed like below pic

Am  I doing in correct way?

please help me .
Thanks

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
       // CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 200);
    _scrollView.tag = 1;
    _scrollView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    NSLog(@"--->%@",_scrollView);

    [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
    [self setupScrollView:_scrollView];
    UIPageControl *pgCtr = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 154, 480, 36)];
     NSLog(@"--->%@",pgCtr);
    [pgCtr setTag:12];
    pgCtr.numberOfPages=10;
    pgCtr.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.view addSubview:pgCtr];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
    // we have 10 images here.
    // we will add all images into a scrollView & set the appropriate size.

    for (int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        // create image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc%d.png",i]];

        // create imageView
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((i-1)*scrMain.frame.size.height+5), 0, 320, 195)];

        // set scale to fill
        _imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        // set image
        [_imageView setImage:image];
        // apply tag to access in future
        _imageView.tag=i+1;
          NSLog(@"--->%@",_imageView);
        // add to scrollView
        [scrMain addSubview:_imageView];
    }
    // set the content size to 10 image width
    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320*3, scrMain.frame.size.height)];
    NSLog(@"--->%@",scrMain);
    // enable timer after each 2 seconds for scrolling.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(scrollingTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}
- (void)scrollingTimer {
    // access the scroll view with the tag
    UIScrollView *scrMain = (UIScrollView*) [self.view viewWithTag:1];
    NSLog(@"--->%@",scrMain);

    // same way, access pagecontroll access
    UIPageControl *pgCtr = (UIPageControl*) [self.view viewWithTag:12];
    NSLog(@"--->%@",pgCtr);

    // get the current offset ( which page is being displayed )
    CGFloat contentOffset = 194;
    NSLog(@"------------------->%f",contentOffset);
    // calculate next page to display
    int nextPage = (int)(contentOffset/scrMain.frame.size.height) + 1 ;
    NSLog(@"%d",nextPage);
    // if page is not 10, display it
    if( nextPage!=10 )  {


        [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, nextPage*scrMain.frame.size.height, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
         NSLog(@"--->%@",scrMain);
        pgCtr.currentPage=nextPage;
        // else start sliding form 1 :)


    } else {

        [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
         NSLog(@"-------------------------------------------->%@",scrMain);
        pgCtr.currentPage=0;
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please implement this code.Hope this works and use these macros.

```
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width

 - (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain
   {
       for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
       {
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"abc%d.png",i]];
           UIImageView *_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 195)];
          _imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
          [_imageView setImage:image];
         _imageView.tag=i;
          [scrMain addSubview:_imageView];
     }

    [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH*3, scrMain.frame.size.height)];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7 target:self selector:@selector(scrollingTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
  }
```

Comment: I think you are using height instead of width.after converting your code to width you will get scroll problem.Because you added +5 to x coordinates.So add 5*3 to contentsize also and Your problem will be resolved

Comment: will you please explain so that I can get what exactly you want. . May be I can solve ?

Comment: frame sizes are in for loop like these  1st image frame size(5,0,320,195),2nd image frame size(199,0,320,195),3rd  image frame size(393,0,320,195) then problem is 2nd  image frame size here the X value is 199 but before only the image is placed as above pic

Comment: @sudheer 
in your case images will be overlap.So you want images to be overlaped ????

Comment: Please priovide the exact design you want to achive

Comment: Overlaping is obvious in your case because your first image width is 320 and you are creating X coordinate from 199 so it will start from 199 + 5 = 204 so 204 < 320 so it will overlap on first image as first image is of 320

Comment: to solve overlaping create X of second image from width of first image  OR create your first image frame 199-5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97373/discussion-between-anil-solanki-and-sudheer-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are wrong at this line:

```
// create imageView
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((i-1)*scrMain.frame.size.height+5), 0, 320, 195)];
```

It should be:

```
// create imageView // change height to width
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((i-1)*scrMain.frame.size.width+5), 0, 320, 195)];
```

Comment: @SudheerKumar Did you try? Same result?

Comment: @SudheerKumar wel. If it is  a new problem, just post another question. :)

Comment: frame sizes are in for loop like these 1st image frame size(5,0,320,195),2nd image frame size(199,0,320,195),3rd image frame size(393,0,320,195)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97189/discussion-between-sudheer-kumar-and-anhtu).

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom view to Scrollview and in Custom view add UIImageview as subview with some padding left and right?

Comment: i have came across the same issue , could you elaborate more ? what should i do to implement like this ?